# How should I go about authenticating an application via HTTP?

Tags: java, security, authentication

I'm making an application that requires it to be authenticated on startup with a "secret key" as defined in a configuration file. I can't have the app call to a database so I'm thinking I need to do a HTTP request, however I am not sure how I should go about doing this and how it can't be exploited.

I just need somewhere to start, thanks!

Comment: What does it need to authenticate with?

Answer (score 0):

You can use SSL. Then to manage trusted certs, you can implement your own `javax.net.ssl.X509TrustManager`. You can use the `javax.net.ssl.X509TrustManager` to manage your .keystore file via standard Java mechanisms. The keystore will contain private keys.

From JavaDoc:

> Instance of this interface manage which X509 certificates may be used to authenticate the >remote side of a secure socket. Decisions may be based on trusted certificate authorities, >certificate revocation lists, online status checking or other means.

Also note that:

> TrustManagers are responsible for managing the trust material that is used when making trust
>   decisions, and for deciding whether credentials presented by a peer should be accepted.

If you extend the `X509TrustManager`, you can read in certificates your private .keystore file as well as certificates trusted by Java. Those live in `JAVA_HOME\lib\security\cacerts`

Comment: You don't need your own TrustManager to get authentication via HTTPS. It's built-in. All you need is an appropriate trust-store.

Comment: It sounds like he is populating a cert store with the secret key, so he will need a trust manager that has knowledge of that custom store, so that the key can be found.